# Get rid of blinking on css 3d transform

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, transform

Here is example:
http://codepen.io/piernik/pen/cKzxq

On chrome I've got ugly blinking when pressing flip button.
How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.card article` should look like this

```
   .card article {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000; /* this line is added */
    }
```

where the last line of the code is added.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HpFDz

Answer (score 0):

use

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

[**FIXED DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLgGd)

Answer (score 0):

`.card .front { z-index: 2; }
 .card .back { z-index: 1; }`

Add the above to your code, and it should be good. The flip is getting confused on which layers should be displayed, which produces that strobe effect.

(Side note, I visited Warsaw last year and loved it!)